# Parallel.Foreach in two foreach loops

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I have list of objects which are grouped by one column as below.

I have millions of records, and it is taking more than 30 minutes. How can I write the below code efficiently?

```
List<Voter> voterList = new List<Voter>();

IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MemberInfo>> groupByLastName = infoList.GroupBy(info => info.LastName).Select(i => i);

foreach (List<MemberInfo> lastName in groupByLastName)
{
    foreach (MemberInfo member in lastName)
    {
        MemberInfo info = memberService.GetMemberDetails(member.FirstName);

        if (info.Age > 18)
        {
            voterList.Add(new Voter{
                VoterId = member.VoterId,
                Age = member.Age
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What the GetMemberDetails do?

Comment: It get details from wcf service

Comment: I would suggest not using "var" in posted questions.  It is much harder to see what the variable-type is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use Parallel.ForEach
2. Add your result object to a thread safe collection.

Below is some pseudo code.  I can't tell what objects you have at your disposal because your original post uses "var" multiple time.

```
 BlockingCollection<Voter> bc = new BlockingCollection<Voter>();


 Parallel.ForEach(myCollection, (e) => { 

     bc.Add(e);

 });
```

---

So I would first collect all of your inputValues (to your wcf)

ICollection allTheInputLastNames = new List();

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MemberInfo>> groupByLastName = infoList.GroupBy(info => info.LastName).Select(i => i);

foreach (List<MemberInfo> lastName in groupByLastName)
{
    foreach (MemberInfo member in lastName)
    {
       allTheInputLastNames.add(member.FirstName);
    }      
}
```

Now, because you have so many, hopefully this runs fairly quickly.

Now that you have collected all the inputs, you want to use the Parallel.ForEach.

I've created a generic example below.

Where I have inputValues, you would have your allTheInputLastNames.

Where I create a new ResultObject, you would make your wcf-service call.

and where I do a "StringLength % 2", you would your info.Age check.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyApp.ParallelStuff
{
    public class ParallelExampleOne
    {

        public void ExampleOne()
        {

            ICollection<string> inputValues = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                inputValues.Add("MyValue" + Convert.ToString(i));
            }

            CancellationTokenSource ct = new CancellationTokenSource();

            BlockingCollection<ResultObject> finalItems = new BlockingCollection<ResultObject>();

            Parallel.ForEach(inputValues, (currentInputItem) =>
            {
                ResultObject ro = new ResultObject(currentInputItem.Length, currentInputItem);

                if (ro.StringLength % 2 == 0)
                {
                    finalItems.Add(ro);
                }

            });

            Console.WriteLine("ExampleOne.finalItems.Count={0}", finalItems.Count);
            string temp = string.Empty;
        }

        public void ExampleTwo()
        {

            ICollection<string> inputValues = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                inputValues.Add("MyValue" + Convert.ToString(i));
            }

            CancellationTokenSource ct = new CancellationTokenSource();

            BlockingCollection<ResultObject> finalItems = new BlockingCollection<ResultObject>();

            ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount, CancellationToken = ct.Token };

            ParallelLoopResult results = Parallel.ForEach(inputValues, options, currentInputValue =>
            {
                ResultObject ro = new ResultObject(currentInputValue.Length, currentInputValue);

                if (ro.StringLength % 2 == 0)
                {
                    finalItems.Add(ro);
                }

            });

            Console.WriteLine("ExampleTwo.finalItems.Count={0}", finalItems.Count);

            string temp = string.Empty;
        }



    internal class ResultObject
    {
        internal int StringLength { get; private set; }
        internal string OutputValue { get; private set; }

        public ResultObject(int stringLength, string inputValue)
        {
            this.StringLength = stringLength;
            this.OutputValue = inputValue + "MyOutputSuffix";
        }
    }

}
```

Also note how you can read my code, because I did not use "var" for my variable declarations.

Comment: I am not getting all the details. means not all the objects.

Comment: I removed 'var' from my initial post

Comment: You removed one of your var's.  Please remove them all.

Comment: I've appended my answer.

Comment: Just a note.  This is a entry into the world of P.ForEach.  It has caveats.  See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-4-blockingcollectionextensions/  https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2017/02/05/curious-case-of-parallel-foreach-with-blockingcollection/   A few items I had in my bookmarks.

Comment: https://www.wipfli.com/insights/blogs/connect-microsoft-dynamics-365-blog/improving-processing-performance-parallelforeach